# How to get TONE from GDELT GKG table from Google BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, gdelt

```
SELECT
DATE,
EXTRACT(YEAR FROM DATE) AS year,
FIPS as Country,
LOCATIONS,
AVG(TONE) as Avg_Tone,
AVG(Positive Score) as PositiveS,
AVG(Negative Score) as NegativeS,
COUNT(*),
From `gdelt-bq.gdeltv2.gkg_partitioned`,
`gdelt-bq.extra.sourcesbycountry` country,

Where
DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2002-01-01') AND TIMESTAMP('2020-12-31')
AND SourceCommonName=country.Domain
AND Location like '%CH%'
GROUP BY Year,Country
ORDER BY  Year,Country
```

Codebook link is http://data.gdeltproject.org/documentation/GDELT-Global_Knowledge_Graph_Codebook-V2.1.pdf
The V1.5TONE has TONE, Positive Score and Negative Score and so on.
I want to count the average Tone by year.
How to get it from Big Query.

Comment: Please show in the future some more of your work before asking. Providing a query which provides all needed columns is a must and it should be runnable or state which part is the problem. The V1.5TONE is not a column, it is the V2Tone, right? Also think of reducing the quered data amount if possible (for a test to help you, I do not want to spend 270 GB query data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the need to cast and split the fields first.

- The `date` is a value formated as "yyyymmdd....". Therefore, I suggest casting the value as a string and consider the first four characters as the year.
- There is no `V1.5TONE` column, but `V2Tone`. It consists of a string with several digital numbers seperated by a comma. The string has to be split first. Then each component needs to be casted a decimal number.
- The table `gdelt-bq.extra.sourcesbycountry` should map an url to a single country. It has duplicated countries to one url! To eliminate at least some duplicated value the inner `select` with the group by is used.
- To obtain the values grouped by Year,Country all other dimensional columns need to be commented out.

```
SELECT
#DATE,
substr(cast(date as string),0,4) AS year,
FIPS as Country,
#LOCATIONS,
AVG(cast(split(V2Tone,",")[safe_offset(0)] as decimal )) as Avg_Tone,
AVG(cast(split(V2Tone,",")[safe_offset(1)] as decimal )) as PositiveS,
AVG(cast(split(V2Tone,",")[safe_offset(2)] as decimal )) as NegativeS,
COUNT(*) as counts,
From `gdelt-bq.gdeltv2.gkg_partitioned`
left join
(SELECT Domain, FIPS 
from `gdelt-bq.extra.sourcesbycountry`
group by 1,2) country
on  SourceCommonName=country.Domain

Where
DATE(_PARTITIONTIME) BETWEEN DATE('2020-01-01') AND DATE('2020-01-31')
AND Locations like '%CH%'
GROUP BY Year,Country
ORDER BY  Year,Country
```

Also in `where` segment: Do not mix DATE and TIMESTAMP.

Comment: The data cannot get before 2015 year?  But in website https://blog.gdeltproject.org/the-datasets-of-gdelt-as-of-february-2016/ the GKG have been extend back to 1979 by Fall 2016.

Comment: This dataset starts at 2015-02-19  (2015-02-17 has only 25 rows) `SELECT   _PARTITIONTIME AS Time,  COUNT(1)
FROM   `gdelt-bq.gdeltv2.gkg_partitioned`
  group by 1
  order by 1 `